# SQL select, 3 tables

Tags: sql, select

How can I use select if I have 3 tables?

**Tables:**

```
school_subject(ID_of_subject, workplace, name)
student(ID_of_student, firstName, surname, adress)
writing(ID_of_action, ID_of_sbuject, ID_of_student)
```

I want to write the student's name and surname (alphabetically) who have `workplace=home`.

Is this possible? And how to alphabetize?

```
SELECT s.firstName, s.surname 
FROM  student S, school_subject P, writing Z
WHERE P.workplace = 'home' 
      AND P.ID_of_subject = Z.ID_of_subject 
      AND Z.ID_of_student = s.ID_of_student;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.firstName, s.surname 
FROM  student S INNER JOIN  writing Z
ON Z.ID_of_student = s.ID_of_student
INNER JOIN school_subject P
ON P.ID_of_subject = Z.ID_of_subject
WHERE P.workplace = 'home'
ORDER BY S.firstName, S.surname  // Sort the list
```

Answer (score 0):

To order alphabetically the result it is possible to use **ORDER BY** keyword. So your query becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.firstName, S.surname 
FROM  student S, school_subject P, writing Z
WHERE P.workplace = 'home' AND 
P.ID_of_subject = Z.ID_of_subject AND
Z.ID_of_student = S.ID_of_student
ORDER BY S.surname, S.firstName
```

The **DISTINCT** keyword is necessary, because in writing table there are eventually more tuples given keys ID_of_subject and ID_of_student. 

So this is necessary to avoid repeating firstName and surname many times.

Answer (score 0):

Note that each student is identified by `ID_of_student`, not by `firstName` and `surname`, so as [@danjok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2882011/danjok) said use `DISTINCT` if you only want the name and surname.

If you want to select all students that satisfy your requirement (even if two or more students have the same `firstName` and `surname`), you should including `ID_of_student` on `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT S.ID_of_student, S.firstName, S.surname 
FROM  student S 
INNER JOIN  writing W ON W.ID_of_student = S.ID_of_student
INNER JOIN school_subject P ON P.ID_of_subject = W.ID_of_subject
WHERE P.workplace = 'home'
ORDER BY S.firstName asc, S.surname asc
```